# Is there a way to have a conditional "IN" statement in the WHERE clause of a procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's say I have a table called "Student" with the following columns: FirstName, LastName, Grade. Now let's say I have a procedure called "getStudents" where you can pass a list of comma delimited grades to select from. It looks something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getStudents] (
@GradeList VARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN
     --Declare temporary table for grades
     CREATE TABLE #Grades (Grade varchar(50))

     --Insert the grades from @GradeList parameter into the temp table
     INSERT INTO
          #Grades
     SELECT value AS Grade
     FROM
          --This is a function that will split the comma delimited list and return the values
          [dbo].[SplitValues] (@GradeList)

     --Select all students that are in the grades provided
     SELECT
          FirstName,
          LastName
     FROM
          Student
     WHERE
          Grade IN (SELECT Grade FROM #Grades)
END
```

This is all working as intended. But what we want now is to make @GradeList an optional parameter, if the value of it is NULL then we want to return all of the students. In this simplified example I would just do an IF statement but we actually want to have multiple optional parameters so it has to be part of the same SELECT statement. I was able to get this working with the following logic:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getStudents] (
@GradeList VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
     --Declare temporary table for grades
     CREATE TABLE #Grades (Grade varchar(50))

     --Insert list of grades into a temporary table
     IF @GradeList IS NULL
     BEGIN
          --No grades provided, select all possible values for Grade into temp table
          INSERT INTO
               #Grades
          SELECT DISTINCT
               Grade
          FROM
               Student
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
          --Insert the grades from @GradeList parameter into the temp table
          INSERT INTO
               #Grades
          SELECT value AS Grade
          FROM
               --This is a function that will split the comma delimited list and return the values
               [dbo].[SplitValues] (@GradeList)
     END

     --Select all students that are in the grades provided
     SELECT
          FirstName,
          LastName
     FROM
          Student
     WHERE
          Grade IN (SELECT Grade FROM #Grades)
END
```

So if nothing is passed in, I just add all of the possible values for Grade to the #Grades temporary table. Functionally this works and is doing what we want it to do. However, because we're dealing with large tables here this has added a tremendous amount of overhead to the procedure (now it's taking up to a minute to run, before it was ~1-2 seconds). Is there a way to have the condition in the WHERE clause be dependent on whether or not there is a value for @GradeList?

Comment: Instead of having an IF and then loading two different things into the temp table have an IF and just execute two different queries, one with the WHERE and one without

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT s.FirstName, s.LastName
FROM Student s
WHERE s.Grade IN (SELECT g.Grade FROM #Grades g) OR
      @GradeList IS NULL;
```

There is no need to use a temporary table to store the results.  You can just use `split_string()` directly in the query.  If you do use a temporary table, though, you might as well make best use of it.  Define the `Grade` to be the primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE #Grades (
    Grade varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

This provides more opportunities to optimize the later query.

Comment: Without `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` the single catch all query can give sub optimal plans compared to having two different queries. With `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` there is some additional compilation overhead though.

Comment: This is the answer I needed. I am using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`, as stated in the question I needed a single catch all query because we want to pass in multiple optional parameters where any combination could have values attached.